# How to find in Java if a Cipher needs an IV or not?

Tags: java, security, encryption

I'm building a streaming server that leverages in cryptography to protect the data being transferred. The ciphersuite is being loaded from a configuration file that allows the user to insert the algorithm + cipher mode (ECB, CBC, CTR, … ) + padding that they want.
The problem is that some modes, like ECB, or stream cipher algorithms don't require IV which gives an error when I try to init the cipher. Therefore, my code is not dynamic enough to deal with these situations. I already tried to look online for a way to find if a given algorithm/mode needs IV or not but found nothing.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost all of the [mode of operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation) requires an IV except ECB which some may not even call it a mode of operation. Also, see [this question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/66858/18298) from Cryptography for a small list of encryption modes. The IV is required for [randomized encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_encryption) therefore all have an IV or nonce( number used once). One should **never use** ECB.

Now, you want to encrypt stream. You should use [AES-GCM](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5288) which is an [authenticated encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption) (AE) mode and from this link, you can see that [Netflix](https://medium.com/netflix-techblog/protecting-netflix-viewing-privacy-at-scale-39c675d88f45) uses it. With AE, you can have authentication, integrity, and encryption altogether. You may also choose [Chacha-poly1305](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7539) which is also an AE.

The [TLS 1.3](https://www.ietf.org/blog/tls13/) have both AES-GCM and Chacha-poly1305 as cipher suites. You should choose the TLS as the secure communication between the client and the server. The fragmentation layer of the record layer has a limit as 2^14-byte 16.384 KB. In each fragmentation, you can check that the message is authentic and has the integrity, if not, re-request form the server.